# Accept spelling suggestion in UITextField on return

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

Hey, I have a UITextField where the user can input a word. If there is a spelling suggestion (the little pop up) available for the word written, I would like this suggestion to be used if the user presses return on the keyboard.

Right now, the user has to hit space to change the spelling to the suggestion, erase the space and then press return.

Can this be done? I think it works like I would want it to in most applications I've seen, for example the SMS app.

Comment: See the answer here, it sounds like what you want:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611525/execute-current-uitextfield-autocorrect-suggestion-when-another-button-is-pressed